# Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed when replacing backend service with backend container

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, socket.io

Host Machine: Linux

Container: Alpine

**APP** is the frontend application that is connected with **Backend Service** through WebSocket.

- **APP** is built with node version: 9.6.1.
- **Backend Service** is built with node version: 10.22.1.

When I start **APP** and the **Backend Service** locally on the host machine the connection works successfully.

I am trying to dockerize the **backend service**, created DockerFile(simplified version) like below, and used the dockerfile to create the image and run that image.

```
FROM repo/node:v10.22.1

COPY node/backend-service/package.json node/backend-service/package.json

WORKDIR /node/backend-service
RUN npm install --unsafe

CMD [ "/usr/bin/dumb-init","--","/usr/bin/node","/node/backend-service/index.js" ]

EXPOSE 8811
```

Everything works correctly and containers are created successfully from the backed service image. I running the backend service without network isolation like below:

```
docker run --network host backend-service-image
```

The communication between the APP(running locally on the host machine) and the backend service(running on the container without network isolation) is not working. It throws the error below:

```
[2021-08-03 14:52:14.455] [ERROR] backend_service/index.js - [MASTER: 8] Uncaught exception:  Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:636:16)
    at Socket.socketEventHandlers.(anonymous function) (/node/backend_service/src/routes/session.js:67:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.onevent (/node/backend_service/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/node/backend_service/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/node/backend_service/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/node/backend_service/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/node/browser_service/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/node/backend_service/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

What I find strange is that is working when the backend service is started on the host machine but not working when running on the docker container that hasn't network isolation.

I will appreciate any hints or guides in solving the issue.

Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of hours of debugging the problem was that a custom node dependency required a configuration file that wasn't present in the container.

After adding the missing configuration file, the worker started and connected successfully to APP.  This `ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED` came from a worker terminated due to not find the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes, after doing `npm install` for missing dependencies, it worked like a charm.